# Splitting a python string using re on unicode and text

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to split a long string based on unicode and text (Chinese) punctuation. How do I do this?

```
def split1(s):
    temp1 = re.split(r"(;|:|•|。|；|：)", s)
    temp = re.split(u"([\u3002|\uFF01|\uFF1F])", temp1)
    i = iter(temp)
```

UPDATE:
I'm hoping to split the string s based on regular text and unicode text.

Comment: And what happens?  What should happen?  What have you tried?

Comment: what went wrong with above code and what's your desired output?

Comment: Maybe `def split1(s): return re.split(ur"([\u3002\uFF01\uFF1F;:•。；：])", s)`? Please add some example and expected output.

Comment: @Malvolio the code above will return an error because temp1 is a class of 're' and no longer a string. My desired output is to split the string s twice based on the two regexes

Comment: @Akshay Nevrekar see above comment

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks it looks like your version works. Does it matter whether the unicode is first in the regex?

Comment: No, it can be anywhere until it does not break the pattern.

Comment: @echan00 -- I mean, add all this information to your question (and similar information to all future questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
def split1(s): 
    return re.split(ur"([\u3002\uFF01\uFF1F;:•。；：])", s)
```

It does not make sense to split the two patterns since the only purpose to use them is to tokenize a string into the chars that match the regex and those that do not.

The captured texts will also make part of the resulting list since the whole pattern is wrapped with a capturing group, see [`re.split` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list

Note the `u` prefix, too, it will tell Python 2.x to correctly handle Unicode code units in the string.